# Sails.js - Services vs Helpers

Tags: sails.js

I am new to Sails.js coming from Laravel framework. I have an API i need to use in my Sails project and I wanted to write a mini library using the Services approach. But on the docs page about it https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/services its stated that I shouldn't use Services but Helpers instead which kind of cofuses me - I have around 15 actions on the API I want to use - so should I create 15 different Helpers instead of one Service? That seems really odd to me and it will be a mess. Is there some better approach I am not seeing? 
I see that I can still use Services but I am affraid they will be deprecated soon.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please try do clarify our question further, might ask 2 instead and narrow each one down. Could you write some pseudo code or js code, with demonstrate your intention?

Comment: I don't have any code yet - this is a design question. I will need to call third party REST API in my application (15 different endpoints). So I want to create a Service that will have all necesary code in it even with auth handling. I am trying to understand how Helpers are better in this situation.

Comment: Problem is: SO is more for tangible coding problems usually you should have already some code i.e. implementation which does not work somehow. Software Engineering Overflow might help you, but still you should be more precise what you want, need, already tried and where your problem is. More precision is usually achievable by some diagrams and short logical bullet points. Otherwise it gets very broad and opinion based.

Comment: I prefer services - https://medium.com/@Noitidart/enabling-service-architecture-in-sails-1-x-x-4ba103646cb0 - helpers also confuse me as it has a lot of buy in, have to write helpers in a very specific way. Service architecture will not be deprecated. It's just a global variable.

Comment: Everyone else, I don't think the ones voting to close this are from the SailsJs community. The confusion between helpers and services is real. I voted to reopen this. I voted to reopen so I can add a solution.

Comment: @Noitidart - thanks! That's exactly what I am affraid of. Services are perfect for my use case, but who knows if they are still present in the future. I have stumbled upon Adonisjs framewrok which looks like much more mature Sails.js even though its younger. So I guess we can close this question.